# Thread servicestartarguments still running after stopService

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

In my Android application, I am running service by this example code:

```
startService(new Intent(this, TaxiService.class));
```

After that, there are two threads started like one as service and second as a ServiceStartArguments, then I stop the service by this:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, TaxiService.class));
```

After stopService still I see thread with name ServiceStartArguments.
If i run and stop service n-th I see more threads with name ServiceStartArguments.
Why and how can I stop thread with ServiceStartArguments?
Thanks.

**EDITED**
I found problem, but no solutions. In my service I stared thread like this:

```
thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
thread.start();
mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
```

In Destroy method I have:

```
mServiceHandler.removeCallbacks(thread);        
super.onDestroy();
_started = false;
```

But still thread is running.

Here is part of ServiceStartArguments thread:

```
            _started = true;
            int seven = 0;
            while (_started) {              
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I found solutions. I forgot added to Destroy method this line:

```
mServiceLooper.quit();
```